# Why don't clojure operators match normal logic operations?

Tags: clojure

Would someone please explain clojure's unusual operators?

Why does `or` return first true or last false? Why does `and` return first false or last true?

Why don't they return `true` or `false`?

Comment: As a side note: that's a common property for dynamically typed languages, the same applies e.g. to Python, Ruby, Perl, and Javascript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convenience. Clojure embraces falsey (nil and false are both falsey) and truthy (everything else).

```
(or a b c)
```

Is more convenient than

```
(cond (not (nil? a)) a (not (nil? b)) b (not (nil? c)))
```

Treating nil as false makes expressions terser, and returning values tend to make functions and conditionals more composable. For example

```
(if a b c)
```

In an imperative language would return no result. In Clojure it returns a value so you can compose the expression with other expressions.

```
(or (if a b c) (if d e f))
```

Similarly or and and are more composable with language abstractions when they return a value instead of a boolean.

```
(if a (or b c) d)
```

It really boils down to if you want true/false or truthy/falsey. Truthy/falsey allows for more concise expressions and is the Clojure choice.

Answer (score 3):

This is called [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). Short-circuit operators evaluate minimal set of arguments that is necessary to get result. For example `or` evaluates to `true` when at least one argument evaluates to `true`, so `or` can stop ("short-circuit") evaluating arguments after the first `true` and return it.

It's common for many programming languages (e.g. C++, Java). Clojure additionally takes advantage of its feature that all values can be coerced to boolean so `or` and `and` can return the last evaluated argument rather than corresponding boolean value.

Answer (score 2):

To illustrate what the question is about:

```
user=> (or [1] nil)
[1]
user=> (or nil [1])
[1]
user=> (and [1] nil)
nil
user=> (and nil [1])
nil
```

Here `[1]` is `truthy` and `nil` is `falsey`. Truthy/false is something that can be considered as true/false. Obviously the value `true` is truthy and the value `false` is falsey.

#### Why doesn't and & or return a boolean?

Well, it actually does:

```
user=> (or false true)
true
user=> (or true false)
true
user=> (or false false)
false
user=> (or true true)
true
user=> (and false true)
false
user=> (and true false)
false
user=> (and false false)
false
user=> (and true true)
true
```

So it's not that `and` & `or` is disobeying laws of logic. Their functionality is extended to provide support for other types. And other usages stem from this.

#### Short-cirtuiting

I forgot to mention this, until I saw [Alex Filatov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35033449/42188). If the first expression to `and`/`or` evaluates to truthy/falsey, then the second argument is not evaluated at all:

```
user=> (or true (do (prn :huh) false))
true
user=> (and false (do (prn :huh) true))
false
```

Hence the similarity to `if` & `cond`.

Note that `and` & `or` takes any number of arguments and the same rule applies to third, fourth and further arguments. Basically they evaluate their arguments from left to right, failing as early as possible.

Comment: `[]` is not falsey--as your examples illustrate.